# Как вывести название прикрепленного файла contact form 7?

Tags: wordpress, contact-form7

Как вывести название прикрепленного файла contact form 7?

```
<div class="file-upload-wrapper" data-text="Прикрепите лого для изделия">
[file file-upload-field class:file-upload-field]
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: CF7 ничего не выводит кроме форм. Он отправляет. А код на SO надо размещать кодом, а не картинками.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

можно через js просто имя получить и вывести в нужный элемент

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('input[name="file-upload-field"]').change(function(e){
            var fileName = e.target.files[0].name;
            $('.file-upload-wrapper').attr('data-text', fileName); 
        });
});
```

код вставить в js файл темы или плагина

Comment: Спасибо, работает